# HTML: relative linking in different levels of a tree - methods to ease the work

Tags: html, directory-structure

I'm working at a clients side to complete documentation of a big system with a complex interface for connected systems. The existing document contains some thousands of pages and is written in pure HTML using the only available software on site: Textpad and Notepad++.

The *.html-pages are stored in the filesystem in a tree with up to 6 levels (subdirectories). Most of the pages have a link to one or more overview site(s) (like history, or requirement nr.). This pages are residing on a fixed position in the tree like
    root/list_of_req/reqnnnn.html (nnnn is the number of the spec. requirement)
If I'm working on a level 3 - file, my relative link is going to

```
../../list_of_req/reqnnnn.html
```

If I'm working on a level 4 - file, my relative link is going to

```
../../../list_of_req/reqnnnn.html
```

In many cases I'm using copy and paste to ease my live (and why don't use text already written). Sometimes the sources are on another level. Is there a way to automatize textpad or notepad++ to introduce the right number of

```
../
```

during inserting text? Or could I verify if the link is valid by some editor function?

Remark (inserted about 5 months later): Similar question was discussed at [stackoverflow 7037959](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037959/css-root-directory)

Comment: I know you said that your current project is pure HTML, but is it possible to introduce server-side languages to it potentially? Today similar problems are solved easily with server-side, just look at Magento which has a ridiculously complicated directory structure but has methods to access all important paths.

Comment: No, unfortunately they publish (for closed user group) in some cases copying the html-tree on a cd or harddrive and the user calls only index.htm on his browser (I neglect the path before index.htm). In the whole bunch of files there is only one small active component in javascript and I think it is not possible to pass the link to that component (and with that to extent the path to the right relative path).

Answer (score 0):

why are they in multiple subdirectories? wouldn't it be easier to put them all in the root? I know you said there are thousands but that's still going to be quicker than writing the relative links to each one

Comment: One of the answer is history. On the other hand I could understand that the creators of the documents decided to have a file structure: For example level 2 is saying api\partnersystem1, api\partnersystem2 and a given substructure which is identical. One could think to extract the slashes in the directory structure but then I'm not sure if the resulting long strings will be really displayable in all browsers (old netscape on unix, on every windows platform - still win95 or mosaic is present).

Comment: you're still using win95 and netscape?

Comment: Some of the consumers of the documentation. I not but it is important to use ease, robust HTML.

Comment: ah right, well I've not heard of a way to get your text editor to create automatically relative paths on multiple static HTML pages. Is there any chance you can migrate the site to using a server side language as others have suggested?

Comment: Yes, this is my suggestion to the client. But first I have to close the gap between actual version of the interface and the documentation (a big stack of paper is waiting for me). When the gap is closed then there will be some switch, but we are still in dicussion. In the meanwhile there is enough time to reduce the blister.

Comment: Seems there is a relation to another entry in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689814/how-to-direct-all-the-links-in-html-to-the-root-folder-of-the-website?rq=1). My aim is to have the resulting web pages totalle relocable and no active parts because I don't know the exact environment where my pages will run.

Comment: And the/another answer about "put all in the root": There are 2600 HTML-files.

Comment: hmm I bet there's a python script out there that could automate putting all of them in the root. Do you have a way of scraping the data from all of the pages? Another option would be to convert all of that in to JSON and use https://swagger.io/ it's great, it'll generate API documentation