# How to direct all the links in html to the root folder of the website?

Tags: html, asp.net, server, directory-structure

Since I am asked to develop a web site under company's server, I find it hard to redirect resources to the root of that website. If I use "/" to specify the root directory, all javascripts, images and css files could be used perfectly in localhost. However, if I try to connect to company's server, everything fails since the folder containing all the materials of that web site is only a subdirectory of that server. I tried to use base to link to the root
. It works for javascript and images but somehow css files cannot be used. When I use inspect element, the link of css appears to be ../../stylesheet/some.css while source of javascript appears to be javascript/master.js. I wonder if some one could help me solve the problem since the web site is quite complicated in terms of number of subfolders and it is not possible for me to use ../../../.... to refer to resources. Below is the structure of my project.
[image: structure]

Comment: Using the **document root reference** is indeed the easiest option to use. I don't really understand - what exactly is stopping you from using /javascript/myscript.js?

Comment: Actually javascript works in all cases but css does not work.

Answer (score 1):

1. In .aspx
   Use HttpRequest.ApplicationPath (ref [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.applicationpath(v=vs.110).aspx))

   `<script runat="server">
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           Label1.Text = Request.ApplicationPath;
           Image1.ImageUrl = Request.ApplicationPath + "/images/Image1.gif";
           Label2.Text = Image1.ImageUrl;
       }
   </script>`
2. In .cs
   Use Server.MapPath("~/bin")

Comment: For first method, does that mean I have to redirect all links one by one ?  For second method, I tried to add Server.MapPath("~/"); to page_load and it seems css works but javascript and images cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is hard to achieve that. The approach I am going to use is by copying the folders to the path. Since "/" is directing to the root of that server, it seems this method is more straightforward.
I add an appsetting.

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="link" value="/a/b/c/d/e/myfolder/"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Whenever I need to refer to a resource, I'll use the variable from appsetting to obtain the path. For example,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["link"] %>stylesheet/master.css" />
```

It is not the best solution but I think it can easily achieve the purpose and is kind of easy to maintain so I just post it here.

Comment: Glad you got it solved. However, instead of using `ConfigurationManager`, why not use a simple variable?

Comment: I have many resources that I have direct to root directory and I am testing this on test server only. Once I have finished the web site, it may be uploaded to another server. So saving it on web config is easier for maintenance.