# How do I conclude the right directory path when including in CSS/JS/HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, linker, filepath

considering these directories:

```
/index.html

/static/js/x.js
/static/css/style.css
/static/dist/some_framework_files...
/static/img/x.jpg
/static/fnt/sans_gio.css
```

1. In index.html  I want to `<link>` /static/css/style.css and `<script src="">` /static/js/x.js
2. In style.css I want to `url()` /static/img/x.jpg and `@import`  /static/fnt/sans_gio.css

And some other different cases...

Now I want to know how I should write these files paths in general, how to move to parent directory and so on.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to learn about relative file paths, you can reference this article on CSS-TRICKS: [Quick Reminder About File Paths](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)

> Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:
>
> - Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
> - Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
> - Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts there (and so on...)
> - To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep moving forward

Answer (score 0):

can you try like this! may be the issue will solved i had same issue when i redirect my htmls from child to a parent how i managed was i needed to put whole address  may be there is an easy way

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css">
```

and

```css
 @import url("../styles.css");
     /* same as */
     @import "../styles.css";
```

and in the directory path you can use / or ../ or ../ to check for your files in parent directories!

and also when directing over url make sure you direct it accordingly check this reference too 
[CSS root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037959/css-root-directory)

agree with @jack too see the link he has given!
https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/