# background-image Property of Css is not working

Tags: html, css, background-image

directory:
index.html
Images
   (inside Images folder) Logo.png
CSS

```css
.landing-page_logo{
    display: block;
    background-image: url("Images/Logo.png");
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="landing-page">
  <div class="landing-page_logo">

  </div>
  <h3>Welcome</h3>
  <h4>This is ......</h4>
  <div>
    Animated Text header
  </div>
</section>
```

Image is in correct folder. Tried using `<img>` tag and that was working. But background-image tag is not working

Comment: have you tried adding `/` at start like this `url("/Images/Logo.png");`?

Comment: Where is your CSS file located?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037959/css-root-directory)

Comment: Make sure that you have no spaces in your directory name and I would also recommend to rename your directory to lowercase instead of uppercase (images instead of Images).

Answer (score 3):

If you have your images within folders then try this
background-image: url(/resources/Images/Logo.jpg);
don't forget to put backslash in front of the first folder.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you include the link to the css stylesheet.

Your html should look something like this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <section class="landing-page">
      <div class="landing-page_logo"></div>
      <h3>Welcome</h3>
      <h4>This is ......</h4>
      <div>
        Animated Text header
      </div>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Of course make sure to change 'style.css' to your css file name.