# How to apply the css file in the root folder

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a main CSS file in the root folder and I need the HTML file which is in a subfolder to link it. how can I link?

thanks in advance whoever solve this

Answer (score 3):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../your-css-name.css">
```

Just try to add `../` before the name of your css. It tells the browser to look for css file in the folder one step up in the file hierarchy. More examples you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40627640/15235869